# What can merfolk use to see in the abyss?

Tags: technology, light, merfolk, vision

A particular species of merfolk inhabit the abyss of the pacific ocean, they belonged to the secret clan which was tasked by the Atlantean emperor to seek immortality elixir. The emperor ordered their vocal cord to be removed as a punishment for not able to find the elixir and they are exiled into the abyss, without echolocation they must rely on vision which is similar to humans. I am wondering what can the merfolk use to lit up the abyss without invention of incandescent lightbulb, time period is early 14th century AD?

Comment: glowing plankton lamps? any bioluminescence

Comment: Removing an entire generation's vocal chords would not prevent their children having them.  The question of whether these merfolk's "secret clan" had some magical skills that they could use to e.g. add echolocation to their abilities also arises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Bioluminescent pets

Anglerfish come to mind.

There is evidence that giant squid are bioluminescent and that they use flashes to stun and catch prey. You may also consider for a really heavy metal factor, specially pirate metal. Suggested theme song: Leviathan, from Alestorm.

Comment: i also agree with this